# SCNNode big image on background cause crash

Tags: ios, swift, textures, scenekit

I'm trying to create ruler application with `ARKit` and `SceneKit`. I've decided to create ruler image programmatically depends on measured distance.

Here is an extension that I use to draw ruler:

```
extension UIImage {

    static let dashLineWidth: CGFloat = 2.0
    static let dashDistance: CGFloat = 163.0 / 25.4
    static let rulerFont: UIFont = .systemFont(ofSize: 15.0, weight: .regular)
    static let attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] = [
        NSAttributedStringKey.font: rulerFont,
        NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.black
    ]

    static func drawRuler(width: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {
        let cm = width * 100 // width in centimeters
        let size = CGSize(width: dashDistance * cm * 10, height: 50.0)

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0.0)
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return nil }

        let background = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
        context.addPath(background.cgPath)
        context.setFillColor(UIColor.white.cgColor)
        context.fillPath()

        var i: CGFloat = 0.0
        var counter: Int = 0
        while i < size.width {
            let isLongDash = counter % 10 == 0
            let isPartDash = counter % 5 == 0
            let dashHeight: CGFloat = size.height * (isLongDash ? 0.25 : isPartDash ? 0.15 : 0.07)
            UIColor.black.setFill()
            UIRectFill(CGRect(x: i - dashLineWidth / 2, y: 0.0, width: dashLineWidth, height: dashHeight))

            if isLongDash && counter != 0 {
                let value = "\(counter / 10)"
                let valueSize: CGSize = value.size(withAttributes: attributes)
                value.draw(at: CGPoint(x: i - dashLineWidth / 2 - valueSize.width / 2, y: dashHeight + 5.0), withAttributes: attributes)
            }

            i += dashDistance
            counter += 1
        }

        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }

    func crop(to width: CGFloat, initialWidth: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: (width / initialWidth) * size.width * scale, height: size.height * scale)
        guard let croppedCGImage: CGImage = cgImage?.cropping(to: rect) else { return nil }
        return UIImage(cgImage: croppedCGImage)
    }
}
```

So at first I'm drawing 0.5 meter image only once for better performance and then every time just cropping needed part to display in `SCNNode`.

And here what I'm trying in my `SCNNode` class:

```
var ruler: SCNNode = initRuler()
var initialWidth: CGFloat = 0.5
var rulerImage: UIImage? = UIImage.drawRuler(width: initialWidth)

func updateRuler() {
    guard let geometry = ruler.geometry as? SCNBox else {
        fatalError("Geometry is not SCNBox")
    }
    let width = geometry.width // in meters
    if width > initialWidth - 0.05 {
        initialWidth += 0.5
        rulerImage = UIImage.drawRuler(width: initialWidth)
    }
    guard let croppedImage = rulerImage?.crop(to: width, initialWidth: initialWidth) else { return }
    let texture = SKTexture(image: croppedImage)
    let material = SCNMaterial()
    material.diffuse.contents = texture
    geometry.materials = [material]
}
```

Everything works fine to the moment when the size of `SCNNode` becomes bigger and the image is bigger too. So around 1.3 meters I've got a crash

> validateTextureDimensions:759: failed assertion `MTLTextureDescriptor
>   has width (16501) greater than the maximum allowed size of 16384.'

Any help would be appreciated. I was thinking if I can split an image in parts and then assign in to material. Or is there an another way to do this?

Comment: Have a look at this, it might be something you can use, or recreate in SceneKit: http://www.cimgf.com/2011/03/01/subduing-catiledlayer/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting a single `16501px` wide image to one `SCNode` representing the whole ruler, it makes much more sense to build up your ruler of hundreds of `1cm` segments, each with a texture that you draw programmatically for a ruler segment with a number.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I will try to implement it in this way and get back with the results.

Comment: The app is not crashing anymore using this approach, but I have another headache with positioning those views.

Comment: @mikle94 Awesome! Create a new question describing your issue with positioning the nodes :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50466931/scenekit-get-node-position-after-rotation
here it is :)

Answer (score 0):

First, probably the best thing to do is just find images of rulers from the internet or use something like photoshop in order to make your own, because making it programmatically isn't very fast. The error has something to do with something called MTLTextureDescriptor the problem is you are using to big of a number this may be because the device you are running it on is to small to fit the whole photo.

Comment: I have tried to create solid color image in photoshop with 50000px wide and it is crashing with the same error.

Comment: probably because you don't have 50000 pixels wide screen