# SceneKit get node position after rotation

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, scenekit, scnnode

For example I have two `SCNNode`s with `SCNBox` geometry positioned one after another increasing `x` position property:

`SCNBox(width: 0, height: 0, length: 0.02, chamferRadius: 0)`

Then I want to rotate the first one using `rotation` property with `SCNVector4`, but when rotation happens I want my second node to follow the first one and change its position according rotation of the first one.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26785453/how-to-get-the-real-position-of-a-sub-node-in-scenekit-after-rotation) solution on the web and tried to print node's `position`, `worldPosition` and `presentation.position` but they are all the same value.

Can someone help me to find out how can I obtain node's position after rotation?

Comment: You want the second node to rotate around move around the first one? Like it is in an orbit?

Comment: @SWAT yes, like if they were only one node

Comment: Did you make the second node the child of the first node?

Comment: If you have same values for the position and worldPosition, then your nodes must be child nodes of the rootNode. Make the second node the child of the first node. Your second node should then rotate around the first node, when you rotate the first node.

Comment: @SWAT thank you a lot, I've actually solved this issue following your advice. I have added second node as a subview to the first and then change its position `SCNVector3Zero` with `x` offset.

Answer (score 0):

The position of a node does not change when it rotates. Maybe you could look at connecting the nodes with a physics mechanism such as `SCNPhysicsHingeJoint`? I found this example which could be useful for your scenario:

[image]

http://lepetit-prince.net/ios/?p=3540

Another example:

[image]

http://appleengine.hatenablog.com/entry/2017/08/17/154852